# A nice property of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisor-counting-function

I noticed:

**$P$ is Prime** ($P \geq 2$)  if and only if:

$d(p^n)=d(p^m)+(n-m)$ with $n,m \in \Bbb{Z}$

where $d(x)$ is the ***number-of-divisors function***.

The proof for it is quite simple, but I just wanted to put this out there since I couldn't find it anywhere else.

Comment: Is the proof "$(n+1) - (m+1) = n-m$"?

Comment: Ummm... so what's your question?

Comment: If you have a simple proof, please post it. You could then ask if the proof is correct (or if anyone can find a simpler one). As @DavidG.Stork points out, there is currently no question, just an assertion. (For what it's worth, the "only if" part seems quite easy, but the "if" part strikes me as somewhat trickier.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes. The divisors of $p^k$ are just the $k+1$ numbers $p^0, ..., p^k$. If you take $n>m$ you get $n-m$ new ones added onto the end of the list.

Comment: That's the "only if" part of the OP's "if and only if" assertion.